# How to convert this method from Objective-C to Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to convert a method from the React-native Firebase documentation, from Objective-c code to Swift. But it's not working, can someone lend me a help?

The doc I'm following: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/notifications/ios

This is the Object C part I want to convert and add to the Swift file:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

At the moment, this is my code, see the commented part:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?
  var bridge: RCTBridge!

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    RNFirebaseNotifications.configure()

    let jsCodeLocation: URL

    jsCodeLocation = RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings().jsBundleURL(forBundleRoot: "index", fallbackResource:nil)
    let rootView = RCTRootView(bundleURL: jsCodeLocation, moduleName: "Zepplin", initialProperties: nil, launchOptions: launchOptions)
    let rootViewController = UIViewController()
    rootViewController.view = rootView

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
  }

  /*func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: [UILocalNotification: Any]?) -> Any {
    RNFirebaseNotifications.instance(_, didReceiveLocalNotification, notification)
  }*/

}
```

But of corse, it's not working, because the syntax is wrong... I'm not familiar with Swift.
Can someone lend me a hand?
I would be glad! Thankss in before-hand!!!

**EDIT:**

Sorry if my question was not clear enough. For me, the question was, "how to fix the syntax?", I knew that the syntax was wrong. I had nothing to add to my question, the error Xcode was giving me was expected, obvious because I don't know Objective-C, nor Swift, I was trying in my way. Even if I added the error to the question, I'm sure that something else would error too. That's why I asked if someone could convert it for me, it's only a few lines, so I think I was not asking too much.

Thanks @bsod, for mentionating the tool you posted in the comment!! This is exactly the tool I needed. I didn't know that something like this tool existed.
[image: This is what I needed]

Thanks for everyone that helped me.

Comment: Please explain what exactly is not working. What i s the expected outcome, what do you get. Do you get a  compile error?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting compile error. XCode gives me syntax errors. I don't know how to convert the first code into Swift code. I tried. The commented part of the Swift code is my attempt, but the syntax is wrong, I don't know how to correct it. It's just Objective-C into Swift, thats why I think someone who understands Objective-C and Swift can convert it easily.

Comment: But how do you know it is wrong, do you get an error? And as Li writes below, that method is deprecated - see also the Apple docs?

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting an error in Xcode even before compiling it, the editor shows me red line, and I know that maybe the whole function (commented part of Swift code I posted) is wrong, as I described, there is a syntax error, I tried to convert the Objective C code into Swift, but it didn't work

Comment: Please share the error in your question. Without it, it is impossible to diagnose. See also [ask].

Comment: I didn't put the error because the whole Swift function was converted by my hands from the Objective C, and from the start I knew that there would be something wrong in my code, syntax errors. I've never coded in Swift nor Objective-C before. Here is the screenshot, but I think it wont help too much, its just the code was written wrong, thats expected, as I'm not familiarized with iOS languages well. https://i.ibb.co/jVbMYF2/Captura-de-Tela-2020-01-20-a-s-13-13-26.png

Comment: https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code/ is a tool that I would not solely rely on for this kind of conversion but it is definitely useful, particularly for single lines and syntax lookup

Comment: @bsod Thankss!!! That was exactly what I needed. I just converted my code using the tool you recommended, and the convertion worked, everything compiled correctly in my project, and my app is running. You rock!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
           didReceive notification: UILocalNotification)
```

But this method is deprecated. You might want to consider migrating to the "UNUserNotificationCenter" related APIs.

Comment: Yeah, maybe its deprecated, but for now, I just want to follow the docs from here: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/notifications/ios 

If it works, great! Their project is active and they are updating the deprecated codes. Soon I'll have to fix these deprecated things, but for now, I just need to make it work. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: The problem I have, is that they explain in their docs how to setup their project in Objective-C, but my project was compiled in Swift, because I needed Swift for a specific purpose

Comment: Yes. Just replace that delegate function declaration with the one I've provided, and you are good to go. :)

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help! But I dont know how to put this part of Objective-C code inside the Swift scope you provided: ```[[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];```, this is my current code: https://ibb.co/41RZnV6

Comment: Thanks, this was one part of the code I needed. I missed only the code inside the scope, but I'll accept yours as the answer of the question. For someone that may be looking for the full code, I edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the objective-C bridging header to your project? You need to do that. Once that's done, Xcode's intellisense can actually help you type that statement. It should be something along the lines of   RNFirebaseNotifications.instance().didReceiveLocalNotification(notification)